# What type of audio file should i use with mediaelementjs?

Tags: javascript, audio, mediaelement.js

I am having problems with mediaelementjs as an audio player on different browsers. So the first question is - what file type is the best to use, to make sure that as many browsers as possible? I have been using MP3, but in Firefox on windows, some of the audiofiles gets partly repeated after they have been played the first time. (A small clip from the middle of the sound, is played after the playthrough has finished). Then i tried MP4 - which worked fine with Firefox, but stopped working with Safari on some Macs. It works fine on my Mac, but not on a customer's. Is there anything teh Safari-users need to install, for the sound to be played?

I'm kinda stuck here, so i could use some hints on what to look for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would use two audio formats: MP3 and OGG. MP3 is native on IE (since v9), Safari, Firefox (partially, it depends on the codecs preinstalled on the OS) and Chrome. Ogg is native on Firefox (since v3.5), Chromium and Opera.

As a fallback, the flash player should read the mp3 file.

For your problem, maybe you should specify ogg firstly, and then mp3. So that Firefox could read that file before the mp3 one...

By the way, can you show some code?